# Jackson JSON Mapping exception in java

Tags: java, json, mapping, jackson

Im working with json data that changes sometimes. Sometimes Segment is only a list, and sometimes segments is a object first and then a list. Im streaming the json data from an url, so ive saved it into a txt file few days ago and thas why todays date not displayed.
EDIT: Updated with the json data that changes and added all the snippets i have.
Here are the two different json strings:
**here segment is only a list**

```
{
  "timetableresult": {
    "ttitem": [
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BLT",
                "#text": "Buss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Vasttrafik",
                "url": "http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
                "id": 279,
                "number": 100
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 20:10"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:10"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:10"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:13"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BLT",
                "#text": "Buss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Vasttrafik",
                "url": "http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
                "id": 279,
                "number": 100
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 20:40"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:40"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:40"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:43"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BXB",
                "#text": "Expressbuss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Swebus",
                "url": "http://www.swebus.se/",
                "id": 690,
                "number": 830
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "remarks": {
              "remark": [
                {
                  "@id": "A7",
                  "#text": "Djur ej tillatet"
                },
                {
                  "@id": "AA",
                  "#text": "Endast 2 klass"
                }
              ]
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 20:50"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:55"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:55"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:58"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BLT",
                "#text": "Buss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Vasttrafik",
                "url": "http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
                "id": 279,
                "number": 100
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:10"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:10"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:10"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:13"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BLT",
                "#text": "Buss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Vasttrafik",
                "url": "http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
                "id": 279,
                "number": 100
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:40"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:40"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:40"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:43"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BLT",
                "#text": "Buss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Vasttrafik",
                "url": "http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
                "id": 279,
                "number": 101
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 21:55"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 23:01"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 23:01"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 23:04"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "segment": [
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "B",
                "@type": "BLT",
                "#text": "Buss"
              },
              "carrier": {
                "name": "Vasttrafik",
                "url": "http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
                "id": 279,
                "number": 100
              }
            },
            "direction": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal",
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400300,
                "@x": 12.932004,
                "@y": 57.720838,
                "name": "Boras Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 22:10"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 23:10"
            }
          },
          {
            "segmentid": {
              "mot": {
                "@displaytype": "G",
                "@type": "G",
                "#text": "Gang"
              },
              "distance": 218
            },
            "departure": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7420483,
                "@x": 11.971856,
                "@y": 57.710275,
                "name": "Goteborg Nils Ericsonterminal"
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 23:10"
            },
            "arrival": {
              "location": {
                "@id": 7400002,
                "@x": 11.973479,
                "@y": 57.708895,
                "name": "Goteborg Centralstation",
                "stationinfo": {
                  "@exists": "true"
                }
              },
              "datetime": "2012-11-26 23:13"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The continue is displayed a little further down because of limited characters...

Comment: Can you post the JSON and your beans?

Comment: Do you mean the json data? Excuse me, im kinda beginner so i dont really know what you mean with beans ? thank you.

Comment: Yes the JSON data you're trying to deserialize. Also you could post a snippet from your `JsonTranslator` class around the area in the exception stacktrace

Comment: Yep, exactly. I mean the classes that maps your objects that you're trying to convert. No worries!

(I'm behind a proxy so I cannot directly access your link)

Comment: I've found out that the json data changes. Segments can sometimes be a list and sometimes an object. 

Now the segment looks like this, but i want it to be an object if it is an object, and a list if it is a list. How can i achieve that? 

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

public class TimeTableItem {

    @JsonProperty("segment")
    private List<Segment> segment = new ArrayList<Segment>();

Comment: Here is a snippet from JsonTranslator:   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  TimeTableResponse result = null;
  
  try {
   result = mapper.readValue(json, TimeTableResponse.class);

TimeTableResponse contains the top node.

Comment: Please, edit your question so we can help you better. Just add your json data (if it changes add the various version), and add a snippet of your classes. Few people will download and explore your code, you've to isolate the problem (so post JSON and classes).

Comment: Okey, thank you. Ill make a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Json nodes for it:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"timetableresult\": {\n" +
                "    \"ttitem\": [\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"segmentId\": 1,\n" +
                "        \"value\": \"someVal\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"segmentId\": 2,\n" +
                "        \"value\": \"someAnotherVal\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode jsonArray = node.get("timetableresult").get("ttitem");
        System.out.println(jsonArray.get(1)); //will return null if it couldn't find
    }
}
```

It will automatically create a tree-structure with all needed mappings for your json.

The best maven dependency for Jackson:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The doc: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html